# Program which takes an input of the Alphabet and outputs the character which is next in the Alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
char = str(input())
char1 = ord(char) + 1
print(chr(char1))
if char == "Z":
  print("A")
```

this is the code i have written
when i input Z
it comes up with
[
A
i dont understand where this square bracket comes
can you please explain why this appears and what i could do to fix it thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in that the line `print(chr(char1))` will execute even if `char == "Z"` because it's not in an `else` block. The square bracket arises from the fact that `[` is the next ASCII character after `Z`. One way to fix your code would be to write the following:

```
char = str(input())
char1 = ord(char) + 1

if char == "Z":
  print("A")
else:
  print(chr(char1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to convert to `chr` after adding 1, and you can take advantage of the ternary operator in Python:

```py
char = input() # you don't need to convert to str, input returns a string
print("A" if char == "Z" else chr(ord(char) + 1))
```

**Syntax:**

```
true_val if condition else false_val
```

- `condition`: A boolean expression that evaluates to either `True` or `False`.
- `true_val`: A value to be assigned if the expression is evaluated to `True`.
- `false_val`: A value to be assigned if the expression is evaluated to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a slightly more elegant and flexible solution that avoids `if` conditions, you can pre-define the range of characters you want to cycle through and use the modulo operator `%` so your `+1` automatically cycles through an ASCII range without falling out to the `[`, which is the character after `Z`.

```
chr_range_start = ord('A')  # Set your first character 
chr_range_end = ord('Z')    # Set your last character
chr_range = chr_range_end - chr_range_start

char = str(input())
char1 = chr_range_start + ((ord(char) + 1 - chr_range_start) % (chr_range + 1))
print(chr(char1))
```

If you decided you wanted to cycle through the lowercase a-z instead of A-Z, you can simply replace 'A' with 'a' and 'Z' with 'z' in the first two lines. You could do this for any range of ASCII characters.

If you wanted to change your step to +2 characters, you simply change the first +1 (the second must remain as is):

```
char1 = chr_range_start + ((ord(char) + 2 - chr_range_start) % (chr_range + 1))
```

This would give you `A`→`C` and `Z`→`Β`. If you did this with an `if` condition, you'd have to change it to:

```
if char == 'Y':
    char1 = 'A'
elif char == 'Z':
    char1 = 'B'
```

This can become cumbersome. With the above code, you can arbitrarily change your range as well as your step value without changing code.